# Irreduciblility of $x^3 + 9x + 6 $ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove the irreducibility of $x^3 + 9x + 6 $ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ without using Eisenstein's criterion. What I have done is --

Let assume it is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then it can be written as $$x^3 + 9x + 6 = (a'x^2 + b'x+ c')(d'x + e')$$
$$= a'd'(x^2 + bx + c)(x + e)$$
$$\displaystyle= (x^2 + bx +c)(x+e)$$
$$\displaystyle= x^3 + (b+ e)x^2 + (be + c)x+ ce$$
equating the coefficients of same powers in both sides
$$ b = -e, be+c = 9, ce = 6$$
solving these gives a equation in e $$e^3 + 9e - 6 = 0$$

I am stuck here, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: If you can't use Eisenstein, can you use the rational roots theorem? It's probably easiest since the polynomial is a cubic.

Comment: Well, I want to find out the problem with above argument.

Comment: The problem with the above method is exactly what you see - you end up with the same equation you started with. (I think you got it wrong, I think it ought to be $e^3+9e-6=0$, Why? Because $-e$ is a root of $x^3+9x+6$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are well on your way to proving that any rational root of the equation must be an integer - and you ought to be able to identify the few possibilities for integer roots and test them. Since there must be a linear factor, this concludes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\frac{a}{b}$ is a root, where $a,b$ are relatively prime integers and without loss $b\ge 1$.  Then $$(a/b)^3+9(a/b)+6=0$$
and hence $$a^3+9ab^2+6b^3=0$$
which we rearrange as $$a^3=b^2(-9a-6b)$$
Hence $b^2|a^3$, which is a contradiction unless $b=1$.  Hence all rational roots are integers.  Now the polynomial is strictly positive for $x\ge 0$, and strictly negative for $x\le -1$.  Hence there are no integer roots.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is basically the proof of the rational root theorem applied to this case

Answer (score 1):

First: Your equation for $e$ is wrong. $$6=ce = e(9-be)=e(9+e^2)$$ so $e^3+9e-6=0$.

Second: This technique will always get back (essentially) the same polynomial you started with, so it is generally not a helpful helpful technique.